# Probability of Poisson process interval containing nearby points?

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I came across a problem recently which seems like should be a straightforward application of the Possion distribution but it isn't quite coming together for me. Given a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ what is the probability that, within the unit interval [0,1], at least two events occur within $1/4$ units of each other? (i.e. events occuring at t=0.8 and 0.9 would be a success, but events occurring at t=0, t=0.3, and t=0.9 would be a failure)

I thought about using each of the sub-intervals of size $1/4$ each with a probability $1-(P(k=0)+P(k=1))$ of containing two events; however this approach seems doomed to failure as the sub intervals are not independent.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The distance $T_1$ from $0$ to the first arrival has an exponential distribution with expectation $1/\lambda.$ The distance $T_2$ from there to the second arrival has that same distribution, and $T_2$ is independent of $T_1.$ Similarly $T_3,T_4,\ldots$ The event whose probability you seek can be expressed as$$\begin{align} & \Big[\left( T_2-T_1<\frac 1 4 \text{ and } T_2<1 \right) \text{ or } \left( T_3-T_2<\frac 1 4 \text{ and } T_3 < 1 \right) \\[10pt] \text{ or } & \left( T_4 - T_3 < \frac 1 4 \text{ and } T_4<1 \right) \text{ or } \cdots \cdots\cdots \Big] \end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The distance $T_1$ from $0$ to the first arrival in the Poisson process had an exponential distribution with expectation $1/\lambda.$ The distance $T_2$ from there to the second arrival has that same distribution, and $T_2$ is independent of $T_1.$ Similarly $T_3,T_4,\ldots$ The event whose probability you seek can then be expressed as$$\begin{align} & \Big[\left( T_2-T_1<\frac 1 4 \text{ and } T_2<1 \right) \text{ or } \left( T_3-T_2<\frac 1 4 \text{ and } T_3 < 1 \right) \\[10pt] \text{ or } & \left( T_4 - T_3 < \frac 1 4 \text{ and } T_4<1 \right) \text{ or } \cdots \cdots\cdots \Big] \end{align}$$

The complementary event is
$$
\begin{align}
& \left( T_2-T_1 > \frac 1 4 \text{ or } T_2>1  \right) \text{ and } \left( T_3-T_2>\frac 1 4 \text{ or } T_2>1 \right) \\[10pt]
\text{and } & \left( T_$ - T_3 > \frac 1 4 \text{ or }  T_3 > 1 \right) \text{ and } \left( T_4 - T_3 > \frac 1 4 \text{ or } T_4 > 1 \right). \text{ [full stop]} 
\end{align}
$$
Here we need only finitely many propositions connected by "and".

Some work remains after that! But this shows you how to reduce it to an essentially finite problem.

Comment: This approach makes sense. In computing the final answer would we not need to condition because $T_2 > 1$ is not independent from $T_3 > 1$? I.e. the terms should be $P((T_2 - T_1 > \frac{1}{4}$ or $T_2 > 1)$ and $(T_3 - T_2 > \frac{1}{4}$ or $T_3 > 1)) =   P((T_2 - T_1 > \frac{1}{4}$ or  $T_2 > 1) | (T_3 - T_2 > \frac{1}{4}$ or $T_3 > 1)) \times P(T_3 - T_2 > \frac{1}{4}$ or $T_3 > 1)$